# Is it possible to add a null check to this Query.builder() parameter?

Tags: groovy, nexus

I want to find assets based off of the time it was last_downloaded, but I also want to check the null parameter too, is it possible to add this to the query? This is a query in Nexus 3:

```
tx.findAssets(Query.builder().where('last_downloaded >').param(cutoffDate).and('last_updated >').param(cutoffDate).build(), [repo]).each { asset ->
```

I expect it not to be possible but if anyone knows how to check the null parameter alongside the `last_downloaded`, let me know.

Comment: Have you tried using `.or('last_downloaded').isNull()`?

Comment: Then how would you distinguish between the 'or' and the 'and'?
Example shown below:
Query.builder().where('last_downloaded').isNull().or('last_downloaded >').param(cutoffDate).and('last_updated >').param(cutoffDate).build()

Comment: Maybe like this: `Query.builder().where('last_downloaded').isNull().or('(last_downloaded >').param(cutoffDate).and('last_updated >').param(cutoffDate).suffix(")").build()`